# having a list of most viewed pages

Tags: 2013, list, web-part

Is there any OOTB list/web part for viewing most viewed pages in a site collection (whole site collection)? SP 2013. What is best solution?

Answer (score 0):

I guess we do not have this functionaity in SP OOTB. But if u want...you can have it as custom implementation. You can have a webpart on each page in the site collection and then this webpart could keep the track of each page visit in a list and from there you could get the most viewed page.